# How to write a simple custom HTTP server in Go?

Tags: go

I am new to Go and trying to write a custom HTTP server.  I'm getting a compilation error. How can I implement the `ServeHTTP` method in my code?

My Code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "time"
)


func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}


func main() {
    // Custom http server
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":8080",
        Handler:        myHandler,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }

    err := s.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Server failed: ", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Error while compiling:

```
.\hello.go:21: cannot use myHandler (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in field value:
    func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You either use a struct and define `ServeHTTP` on it or simply wrap your function in a [`HandlerFunc`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc)

```
s := &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":8080",
    Handler:        http.HandlerFunc(myHandler),
    ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write 'and' rather than 'an' in 'You either use a struct an define'?

Comment: how can i add multiple Handler functions ?

Answer (score 6):

in order to work properly, `myHandler` should be an object that satisfy the [Handler Interface](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler), in other words `myHandler` should have method called `ServeHTTP`.

For example, let's say that `myHandler` is custom handler for showing the current time. The code should be like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type timeHandler struct {
    zone *time.Location
}

func (th *timeHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tm := time.Now().In(th.zone).Format(time.RFC1123)
    w.Write([]byte("The time is: " + tm))
}

func newTimeHandler(name string) *timeHandler {
    return &timeHandler{zone: time.FixedZone(name, 0)}
}

func main() {

    myHandler := newTimeHandler("EST")
    //Custom http server
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":8080",
        Handler:        myHandler,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }

    err := s.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Server failed: ", err.Error())
    }
}
```

run this code and access `http://localhost:8080/` in your browser. you should see formatted text like this

```
The time is: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 18:19:46 EST
```

(you should see different time.)

hope this help,

**Further more reading**

[A Recap of Request Handling in Go](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/a-recap-of-request-handling)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct. But http.HandlerFunc(myHandler) simplifies it by automatically adding ServeHTTP method in myHandler thereby satisfying the Handler interface.

Comment: @AnkurS ok, i like OneOfOne answer too. It's more simple :)

Answer (score 5):

You could also define a mux and add handlers to it before assigning it to the server like below.

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}

func main(){

   // define a serveMux to handle routes
   mux := http.NewServeMux()
   // assign a route/todo to a handler myHandler
   mux.HandleFunc("/todo", myHandler)

   // assign a route/todo/notes to an anonymous func
   mux.HandleFunc("/todo/notes", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
       w.Write([]byte("Hello again."))
   })

   s := &http.Server{
      Addr:           ":8080",
      Handler:        mux,
      ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
      WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
      MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
   }

   if err := s.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("server failed to start with error %v", err.Error())
   }
}
```