# [go]Custom Server to handle request with specific path

Tags: http, go

I want to make a api which handles the request which have the path such as 
`http:\\localhost:8080\todo\something` but I need to do using custom server.

Here is the piece of code I have written.

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "time"
    )


func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}


func main() {

    //Custom http server
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":8080",
        Handler:        http.HandlerFunc(myHandler),
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }

    err := s.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Server failed: ", err.Error())
    }
}
```

inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583028/how-to-write-a-simple-custom-http-server-in-go)

My handler accepts all the request such `http:localhost:8080\abc`, `http:localhost:8080\abc` etc
How to give path in custom server so that it handles request only that matches the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use different URL paths, you have to create some `mux`, you can create one, use the default mux provided by go or use a third party mux like `gorilla`.

The following code is made using the standart `http` library provided.

```golang
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/todo/something", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Response"))
    })

    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":8080",
        Handler:        mux,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    s.ListenAndServe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on, though not recommended but a good starting point is to experiment with the DefaultServeMux that also comes with the std lib. The DefaultServeMux is used when you don't supply a mux to the http server.

```
 func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
     io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
 }

 func main(){
     // you can register multiple handlers 
     // as long as it implements the http.Handler interface

     http.HandleFunc("/todo/something", myHandler)
     http.HandleFunc("/todo/thingTwo", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

         something := strings.TrimPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/todo/")
         fmt.Fprintf(w, "We received %s", something)
     })

     http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil) //Will use the default ServerMux in place of nil
 }
```

The idea here is that you can use the default server Mux for testing, create your own Mux like @Motakjuq showed you using the http.NewServeMux() and assign to your server or you can use a thirdparty router lib like [go-chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi), [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) or simply take your pick from a nice collection [here](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#routers) or simply review the [stdlib](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)